# Linux-style path on windows or vice versa

Tags: linux, windows, path

I have a directory that is synchronized between my windows and linux installations via dropbox. In Windows Vista, it appears as `X:\` drive, in Linux (latest xubuntu), it's mounted as `/x/` directory.

The problem is that I'd like this directory to have the `same path` in both systems, so my Eclipse installation can understand it properly. I can imagine that using some kind of trick might exist to tell Linux to dig 'x:\' syntax, or vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NTFS supports symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), so you might be able link `C:/x/`,`D:/x/` etc to `X:/`, and then you can omit the disk prefix and it will assume that you mean the current disk, find the symlink, and go look in `X:/`.  Horribly cludgy, of course, but it's the best I can think of.

```
mklink /d C:\x X:\
```

Comment: This is working for using Emacs' bookmarks across Windows and GNU/Linux.