# Same path on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux-style path on windows or vice versa](https://superuser.com/questions/185989/linux-style-path-on-windows-or-vice-versa)

NOTE: I should have included this in advance. I am very aware this is a very bad idea, that it makes little sense, etc. But sometimes, there are situations outside of our control that drive us to find solutions that make no sense.

We have a requirement for a property file to be placed on both windows and linux without changes and it contains absolute paths. I know that basic "/some/path" works on both, but on Windows, that's a path based on the current drive letter.

Is there some way to specify a path in such a way that it could go across drive letters on Windows?

In other words, if "/D:/some/path" worked on windows (which it doesn't) that path could be created on Linux. Is there something like that that could work?

Comment: this is a Very Bad Idea

Comment: You have a bug - in your requirements.

Comment: This is a Very Bad Idea. But, if you must, you could try using [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention). Maybe //?/C:/path/to/file, which (I _think_) is a valid path in both Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

This really will not work. If you want an absolute path in Windows, it will require the drive letter. Linux doesn't use letters, it just uses mounts on "/". A relative path from the app folder is a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have separate property files for each target OS?  I assume you have to package your application differently (MSI vs RPM or similar), so what's the harm in separate files (which could be generated from a single "base" file to avoid getting out of sync with each other).

It's a much better idea to follow the conventions of the operating system you're targeting for configuration, logging, etc.  Linux has the [Linux Standard Base (LSB)](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) and the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)

For Windows, there seems to be something similar on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc834998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, that would make sense, but unfortunately in this case, it's not what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, allow the paths in the file to be relative, e.g. to the program's installation directory or a similar directory.  Alternatively, if it is your own code that is reading this file, you could allow environment variables in the paths, e.g. `$INSTALL_DIR/lib/foo`.  Your program could then arrange to set `$INSTALL_DIR` to the appropriate directory before reading this file, or it could simply be a magic token which is replaced with the install directory and not a real environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on the nature of your software. Here are a few suggestions.

1. Make the path configurable and store in a properties file
2. Use cygwin and store everything local to the cygwin directory
3. Use Environment Variables.
4. Write your own file system.
5. Send your stakeholder a fish wrapped in a newspaper and politely suggest they reconsider this silly requirement.

I mean  thats all I can really think of.

Comment: So far, I have managed to exercise sufficient self control as to avoid #5 which would be my preferred solution.